# Finding the regular expressions search in jEdit

Tags: jedit

I am not a programmer, I am a book editor, and need to automate a task. I need to be able to load my entire book into a program to add `<p>` before every paragraph, and `</p>` after each one. Currently I have to go through and entire book on notepad and manually do it.

Guido Henkel in his book "Zen of eBook Programming" describes it like this:

- Copy your whole book's text into the text editor.
- Run a regular expressions search and replace.

**Where do I go to do a "regular expression search and replace" in the jEdit program?** Does jEdit need to be set up or have plug-ins installed?

The top of the search box says "find" I have the code I am supposed to use; it's just that when I opened the program, I experienced the shock of being in a strange country. Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using jEdit editor http://www.jedit.org . No plugins are needed to just replacing text by regular expressions.

1. Open the `Search And Replace` dialog via click `Search` in the menu bar and select `Find...`
2. Turn on `Regular Expressions`, put `.+` to the `Search for` box, put `<p>$0</p>` to the `Replace with` box then press `Replace All`